# Laravel Homestead: 403 forbidden on nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx

I just installed Laravel Homestead according to their instructions. When I open http://homestead.app:8000 I get the nginx 403 forbidden HTTP Response.

I have tried setting app/storage permissions to 755, but that didn't work, so I reloaded Vagrant. With no further result.

I also tried changing the nginx configuration, but with no success.

Answer (score 92):

I had the same problem and for me the cause was that in the Homestead.yaml file, I have incorrectly put this:

```
sites:
- map: homestead.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

Instead of the correct syntax:

```
sites:
- map: homestead.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/path/to/public
```

Comment: you need to re-provision after this, I think

Comment: I actually had to had to do /home/vagrant/Code/path/to/public

Comment: In my case, I'd forgotten to add the /public directory ;-P

Comment: Do re-provision by the command  ```vagrant reload --provision```

Answer (score 33):

Another reason for this response can be duplicating your routing with folders in public directory. For example you might have `homestead.app/lists` `GET` route and `lists` folder in your `/public` directory. This will cause the same 403 error (server will assume you are trying to access `/public/lists` directory instead of your `/lists` route).

Comment: This just helped me solve my issue!  I have an audio page on my site (/audio) and in my public folder, has the /audio folder...

Comment: great catch! A safe solution (I think) would be to disable this rule in .htaccess `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, since directory listings are never allowed. Just did this and seems to work fine

Comment: ok, this is actually my case with duplication of /admin/ route and /public/admin directory. But what should i do to fix nginx 403 error without  directory or route renaming? Is it possible?

Comment: You just saved my day!

Answer (score 12):

OK, i got the answer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579107/laravel-homestead-403-forbidden-on-nginx#comment63499114_29805565) after few hours of searching and debugging.

**The problem:**

1. I've got GET route **/admin**
2. Also i've got **/public/admin/** folder with assets inside.
3. And i've got 403 access denied from nginx cause of this duplication;

So, if you don't want to rename route or assets folder, all you need to do is replace

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    #              ^^^^^
}
```

with this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

If you could rename your route or assets folder without any refactor then you could do this without nginx config fixing.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: change "wont" to "don't want" for clarity. tell us the file where this change should go to. eg: /etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite.app

Comment: This is the solution, I also needed to do `vagrant reload` after this

Answer (score 11):

I have been banging my head against the wall dealing with this very same problem, and I just solved it for my case.

I was sure I'd set up the yaml file correctly, but I kept getting the 403 error, and when experimenting with some routes I was getting "input file not specified".

My solution came from http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead and it involved using the serve command. I wasn't adding any additional sites, just trying to anything to get the first site running.

SSH'ing into my vagrant box and using the command "serve my_app_name.app /home/vagrant/Code/path/to/public" did the job. Note that I had already put an entry into my hosts file for this app.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is working! Thank you so much, Hope they fix it in a feature version

Comment: This answer should be accepted as solution. Worked just fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.1 with the latest homestead version, this did not work for me. Instead it made everything else to stop working.

Answer (score 6):

For some people this may be as simple as having git cloned in an existing public folder, e.g:

```
- map: hello-world.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/hello-world
```

The correct folder structure is:

```
- map: hello-world.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/hello-world/public
```

Another good note is ignoring the laravel docs on editing hosts file, using git shell, or cygwin (windows) to install vagrant hostsupdater, and simply adding entries for hosts and aliases to ~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml file.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest checking the nginx logs - use `sudo tail /var/log/nginx/homestead.app-error.log`

Answer (score 5):

**Here's the full solution steps:**

1. run `homestead edit`
2. add **`/public`** to the end of your directory

`sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /full/path/to/the/laravel-app/public`

3. run `homestead halt && homestead up --provision`

Answer (score 2):

Change the config of Nginx

Put that line in 'location /' section:

```
try_files $uri $uri/public/index.php?$query_string;
```

If its not working then replace your 'public' with the folder name that content 'index.php',

That worked great with me using ServerPilot,

Good luck!.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, for testing purposes I had only phpinfo.php file in the *public* directory. The server kept showing 403 errors until I placed a file named ***index.php*** into the public folder!

Comment: Yes i had a similar issue because i had removed my whole /public dir from source control then when i (later) cloned that version of the project i couldnt get it running! Duh

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you are getting **nginx 403 forbidden** HTTP Response because of improper configuration of **sites** in `Homestead.yaml`,
if you configure it properly it should work.

**How to solve the issue step by step:**

1) Goto your vagrant box and create the laraval app

```
$vagrant ssh
$cd ~/code

$#lets create basic blog 
$laravel new blog
    Crafting application...
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    ........

$cd blog
$ll
   # You should be able to see public folder in this dir.
   # this is the entry point for your application.
   # this is your public dir: ~/code/blog/public
   # more explicitly: /home/vagrant/code/blog/public

$exit   # exit ssh
```

2) Update the Homestead.yaml with proper site info

```
 - map: homestead.app
   to: /home/vagrant/code/blog/public  # should be same as in step1
```

3) Re-provision your vagrant

```
$vagrant reload --provision
```

You should be able to access it now using http://homestead.app
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this when I tried manually creating my first site. @GregD's answer helped me discover the problem! Vagrant/Homestead/Laravel will typically get everything running smoothly on its own if you use the built-in features.

Homestead's configuration file comes preconfigured for one site, located in `/Code/Laravel/`. Some steps to get this test bed up and running:

1. [Install Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/homestead) (remember to set your hosts file)
2. `vagrant up` and connect to your virtual machine via ssh ([Chrome Secure Shell](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo) is great if you don't have a terminal on your machine already)
3. [Download and set up](http://laravel.com/docs/quick) the [PHAR package](http://laravel.com/laravel.phar)
4. `cd ~/Code`
5. `laravel new Laravel`.
6. Browse to http://homestead.app:8000

This will create your first site with appropriate permissions. You can model future sites after the permissions on this one, or just use the "sites" node of `Homestead.yaml` and `laravel new <site>` to make new sites in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Access in your browser

```
homestead.app/public
```

Before installation of laravel/laravel with composer within **/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public**

Answer (score 1):

Configuring Nginx Sites :

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/project1/public

Answer (score 1):

To fix, ssh into your homestead, then do :
`nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/the-name-of-your-project.test`

After that all you need to do is get rid of `$uri/` that you will find in the `location` object , then do `vagrant reload` and error should be fixed.

[image: Nginx 403 error fix]

Comment: This works, but the next time you provision the machine this change is lost.

Comment: I'm aware, but then again provisioning does not happen that often.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to move the address in the host file to the bottom of the file. It happend to me twice.

Answer (score -1):

Check nginx error in you vagrant box

## vagrant ssh

## sudo cat var/log/nginx/yoursite.tld-error.log

"*1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /home/vagrant/code/public/index.php (No such file or directory)" "

Change in Homestead.yaml

## nano Homestead.yaml

to
map: homestead.app
to: /home/vagrant/code/Laravel/public

then..

## vagrant reload --provision