# Laravel: 403 when trying to access any folder/file in /public

Tags: http, laravel, nginx, laravel-4, homestead

I got Laravel's 4.2  homestead server (nginx).
So, if I write in any view something like this:

```
<script src="media/js/application.js"></script>
<link rel="icon" href="media/img/branding/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="media/css/markdown.css">
```

It includes all files propetly, but code below doesn't work (**403 error**):

```
<div style="background-image: url(media/img/image.jpg)"></div>
```

Also, if I try to access some folder/file in /public directly it returns 403 too. Why? That's my nginx site config (the truth is this is a auto-generated homestead config):

```
vagrant@homestead:~/work/Timetable$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/timetable.dev 
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name timetable.dev;
    root "/home/vagrant/work/Timetable/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/timetable.dev-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/timetable.dev.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/timetable.dev.key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You gave two questions, for the first one :

Your media folder should have been under assets folder, then to include it :

`asset('media/img/image.jpg');`

For the second question , it already exists on this site : [Laravel Homestead: 403 forbidden on nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579107/laravel-homestead-403-forbidden-on-nginx)

Comment: 1) doesn't work, 403    2) My nginx is listening /public folder already

Comment: Also, it's Laravel 4.2, it doesn't have a assets folder

Comment: `asset` isn't just for assets and it doesn't look in an assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

`<div style="background-image: url(/media/img/image.jpg)"></div>`

add extra `/` before media.

Comment: By my frontend experience I know that slash in the start of html/css paths is not required

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with nginx, but are you 100% sure that the folder permissions are what they should be? 403 translates to forbidden meaning that somewhere in your config or permissions, it is disallowing access.

What if you try `chmod -R 777 public`? Does it work if you do that?