# Laravel 5.4 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: laravel-5.4

My front theme opened, there is no problem with that but it gives me this error when i opened admin theme... Here is my codes;

Route file;

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {

Route::get('/','AdminController@getIndex'); });
```

and controller;

```
public function getIndex(){
    return view('back.index'); }
```

Where do i make mistakes ?

Comment: What is the exact error you get ?

Comment: Thats error :/ http://prntscr.com/fw2a30

Comment: Looks like it's not relative to Laravel, have you looked at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443918/403-forbidden-on-nginx-1-4-6-ubuntu-laravel  or this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579107/laravel-homestead-403-forbidden-on-nginx#comment63499114_29805565 Tell me if it's not solving your problem I would help you !

Comment: in fact i solved one hour ago.. i added "index" to url like this -> Route::get('/index','AdminController@getIndex'); }); its working. But still confused why main("/admin") url not working ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was that I had a route going to '/admin' and a folder within my public folder called 'admin'.

So NGINX was first trying to go into the 'admin' directory before it got to render the routes, which since there wasn't an index.php in the admin directory, it gave the error.